# Dúvida em exercício de herança em C#

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Estou tentando resolver um exercício de herança e encontrei uma dúvida que vi que tem chance de aparecer em outros lugares e por isso achei que devia perguntar aqui. O exercício pedia pra primeiro criar uma classe `Voo` que representa um voo de avião e é capaz de manipular informações sobre ocupação de assentos, sendo que parte dos requerimentos é o fato de cada voo ter no máximo 100 assentos.

Depois é pedido pra criar uma classe herdeira que permite a definição do número de cadeiras máximo e dividir o avião em fumantes e não fumantes. Com relação a parte dos fumantes eu sei implementar. O que eu não sei é o número variável de cadeiras por causa da forma que implementei a classe base.

Como há 100 assentos, eu criei um array de bool de tamanho 100 na classe base em que a `i`-ésima entrada é `true` se o assento `i` está ocupado. Basicamente eu fiz isso inicializando o array no construtor da seguinte forma:

```
public class Voo
{
    private bool[] ocupacaoAssentos;

    public int Numero { get; private set; }

    public Data Data { get; private set; }

    public Voo(int numeroVoo, Data data)
    {
        this.Numero = numeroVoo;

        this.Data = data;

        this.ocupacaoAssentos = new bool[100];
    }
}
```

Então os métodos manipulam esse array. O problema é que a classe herdeira não teria como modificar isso. Até onde eu sei, no C# o construtor da classe herdeira sempre chama o construtor da classe base.

Uma solução possível (em C#) seria implementar isso com uma classe de coleção que não tem tamanho fixo e então criar um campo readonly estático que diz o máximo de assentos e então modificar ele na classe herdeira e a partir daí fazer verificações pra que tudo fique dentro dos limites. Não sei se do ponto do exercício seria válida, porque o exercício é em Java e não sei se o Java tem essas classes de coleção como o C#.

Mas e se eu não tivesse como modificar a classe base por alguma razão ou por algum outro detalhe do problema eu simplesmente não tivesse como aplicar uma solução desse tipo? Como eu poderia lidar com isso? Esse é um caso que me parece que a classe base é mais geral que a classe herdeira.

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas a questão da classe filha ter que manipular o array (não sei se isso é realmente necessário, não fiz essa análise), você poderia mudar o array para ser `proteceted`, assim a filha teria acesso. Tem que pensar bem, são poucos casos que um campo protegido realmente é necessário. Em C# é muito mais comum usar uma coleção (uma lista por exemplo) do que um array. Um array pode ser considerado detalhe de implementação ou otimização prematura, em alguns casos. A classe base tem que ser mais geral mesmo.

Comment: Então @bigown, trocando pra classe de coleção me pareceu algo mais bem feito, mas a solução de ter um campo readonly estático dizendo o máximo me parece ruim também, porque ele teria que ser protected. Nesse caso, pensei em fazer diferente: por o número de assentos variável na classe base com padrão 100 e então usar a classe filha só pra implementar a funcionalidade dos fumantes. Assim faria mais sentido a herança?

Answer (score 4):

Existem várias formas de fazer isso. Uma forma simples é criar um novo construtor que permita a definição do número de assentos:

```
public Voo(int numeroVoo, int numeroAssentos, Data data)
{
   ...
   this.ocupacaoAssentos = new bool[numeroAssentos];
   ...
}
```

Na classe herdeira invoque esse novo construtor usando ":base()":

```
public ClasseHerdeira(int numeroVoo, int numeroAssentos, Data data)
{
   :base(numeroVoo, numeroAssentos, data) { }
}
```

Outra forma é criar um método setNumeroAssentos() na classe Voo e invocar esse método no construtor da classe herdeira.

Answer (score 2):

Para acessar o construtor herdado utilize `:base` que você vai acessar os construtores da classe

O base palavra-chave é usada para acessar os membros da classe base de dentro de uma classe derivada (*Tradução*).

Referência: [base (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx)

***Exemplo***

*Classe Base*

```
public class Voo
{
    private bool[] ocupacaoassentos;
    public int Numero { get; private set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; private set; }

    public Voo()
    {
        this.Numero = 0;
        this.Data = DateTime.Now;
        this.ocupacaoassentos = new bool[100];
    }
    public Voo(int NumeroVoo, bool[] OcupacaoAssentos)
    {
        this.Numero = NumeroVoo;
        this.Data = DateTime.Now;
        this.ocupacaoassentos = OcupacaoAssentos;
    }
    public Voo(int NumeroVoo, DateTime Data, bool[] OcupacaoAssentos)
    {
        this.Numero = NumeroVoo;
        this.Data = Data;
        this.ocupacaoassentos = OcupacaoAssentos;
    }               
}
```

---

*Classe Derivada (Herança da classe Voo)*

```
public class HerdaVoo: Voo
{
    //Construtor sem paramentros igual classe base
    public HerdaVoo()
        :base() { }

    //Construtor com paramentro seguindo o construtor da classe base
    public HerdaVoo(int NumeroVoo, bool[] OcupacaoAssentos)
        : base(NumeroVoo, OcupacaoAssentos) { }

    //Construtor com paramentro seguindo o construtor da classe base
    public HerdaVoo(int NumeroVoo, DateTime Data, bool[] OcupacaoAssentos)
        :base(NumeroVoo, Data, OcupacaoAssentos) { }
}
```

Perceba que ele vai acessar os 3 Construtores da classe base observe na figura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Codificação*

```
HerdaVoo herda = new HerdaVoo(100, DateTime.Now, new bool[500]);
```